# Product pages open with errors

Tags: product, exception

I don't know if it is the reason to introduce custom CSS.
Now my website opens some product pages, which prompts the following error.
But some product pages are open normal. **How can I solve it?**
[image]

Comment: please shre your product.php file code

Comment: I have solve it, the product.php miss! thanks!